# Count parts of total value as columns per row (pivot table)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot-table

I'm stuck with a seemingly easy query, but couldn't manage to get it working the last hours.

I have a table `files` that holds file names and some values like records in this file, DATE of creation (`create_date`), DATE of processing (`processing_date`) and so on. There can be multiple files for a create date in different hours and it is likely that they will not get processed in the same day of creaton, in fact it can even take up to three days or longer for them to get processed.

So let's assume I have these rows, as an example:

```
create_date            | processing_date
------------------------------
2012-09-10 11:10:55.0  | 2012-09-11 18:00:18.0
2012-09-10 15:20:18.0  | 2012-09-11 13:38:19.0
2012-09-10 19:30:48.0  | 2012-09-12 10:59:00.0
2012-09-11 08:19:11.0  | 2012-09-11 18:14:44.0
2012-09-11 22:31:42.0  | 2012-09-21 03:51:09.0
```

What I want **in a single query** is to get a grouped column truncated to the day `create_date` with 11 additional columns for the differences between the `processing_date` and the `create_date`, so that the result should roughly look like this:

```
create_date   |   diff0days   | diff1days | diff2days | ... | diff10days
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-09-10    |       0             2           1       ...        0
2012-09-11    |       1             0           0       ...        1
```

and so on, I hope you get the point :)

I have tried this and so far it works getting a single aggregated column for a `create_date` with a difference of - for example - 3:

```
SELECT TRUNC(f.create_date, 'DD') as created, count(1) FROM files f WHERE TRUNC(f.process_date, 'DD') - trunc(f.create_date, 'DD') = 3 GROUP BY TRUNC(f.create_date, 'DD')
```

I tried combining the single queries and I tried sub-queries, but that didn't help or at least my knowledge about SQL is not sufficient.

What I need is a hint so that I can include the various differences as columns, like shown above. **How could I possibly achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically the pivoting problem:

```
SELECT  TRUNC(f.create_date, 'DD') as created
,       sum(case TRUNC(f.process_date, 'DD') - trunc(f.create_date, 'DD')
                  when 0 then 1 end) as diff0days   
,       sum(case TRUNC(f.process_date, 'DD') - trunc(f.create_date, 'DD')
                  when 1 then 1 end) as diff1days   
,       sum(case TRUNC(f.process_date, 'DD') - trunc(f.create_date, 'DD')
                  when 2 then 1 end) as diff2days   
,       ...
FROM    files f 
GROUP BY 
        TRUNC(f.create_date, 'DD')
```

Comment: Your answer suits my needs best, I added "else 0" to the cases to not have NULL. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CreateDate,
    sum(CASE WHEN DateDiff(day, CreateDate, ProcessDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Diff1,
    sum(CASE WHEN DateDiff(day, CreateDate, ProcessDate) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Diff2,
    ...
FROM table
GROUP BY CreateDate
ORDER BY CreateDate
```

Comment: I don't think Oracle has a `DateDiff` function, but this would work in SQL Server

Comment: That's true, DateDiff is not available, but DATEs can simply be subtracted, so that's basicly the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Oracle 11g you can also get desired result by using `pivot query`.

Here is an example:

```
  -- sample of data from your question
  SQL> create table Your_table(create_date, processing_date) as
  2  (
  3        select '2012-09-10', '2012-09-11' from dual union all
  4        select '2012-09-10', '2012-09-11' from dual union all
  5        select '2012-09-10', '2012-09-12' from dual union all
  6        select '2012-09-11', '2012-09-11' from dual union all
  7        select '2012-09-11', '2012-09-21' from dual
  8   )
  9  ;

Table created



 SQL> with t2 as(
  2    select create_date
  3         , processing_date
  4         , to_date(processing_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  
                      - To_Date(create_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') dif
  5      from your_table
  6    )
  7      select create_date
  8           , max(diff0) diff0
  9           , max(diff1) diff1
 10           , max(diff2) diff2
 11           , max(diff3) diff3
 12           , max(diff4) diff4
 13           , max(diff5) diff5
 14           , max(diff6) diff6
 15           , max(diff7) diff7
 16           , max(diff8) diff8
 17           , max(diff9) diff9
 18           , max(diff10) diff10
 19        from (select *
 20                from t2
 21                pivot(
 22                       count(dif)
 23                       for dif in ( 0 diff0
 24                                  , 1 diff1
 25                                  , 2 diff2
 26                                  , 3 diff3
 27                                  , 4 diff4
 28                                  , 5 diff5
 29                                  , 6 diff6
 30                                  , 7 diff7
 31                                  , 8 diff8
 32                                  , 9 diff9
 33                                  , 10 diff10
 34                                  )
 35                     ) pd
 36             ) res
 37      group by create_date
 38  ;
```

Result:

```
Create_Date Diff0 Diff1 Diff2 Diff3 Diff4 Diff5 Diff6 Diff7 Diff8 Diff9 Diff10
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
2012-09-10    0     2     1     0     0     0     0    0      0     0     0 
2012-09-11    1     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0     0     1
```

Comment: That looks great and I tried it, it works. But that's hard-coded dates, I want to use the date in the corresponding row. Is this possible with the pivot query, too? Thank you!